# How do I make it so that my program reads multiple txt files and creates it into a dataframe for python?

Tags: python, pandas, file, glob

Currently I am making a program to cycle through multiple txt files and turn them into dataframes so that the data can be analysed. I have used the glob function to return a list of txt files. After that, I have created a for loop which cycles through every item in the list. Then I use the read_csv function to read this data, data.head() to print it. I know my code is probably really stupid but please help me fix it. I am currently at a loss for what to do.

Here is my original code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Datapoints/*.txt'
dataframes = []
for filename in glob.glob(path):
  data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter='\t')
  data.head()
```

For reasons I do not understand (I am a novice when it comes to programming), my code is getting a lot of errors:

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-52-f940d2e4b46d> in <module>()
      2 dataframes = []
      3 for filename in glob.glob(path):
----> 4   data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter='\t')

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2035     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2036         try:
-> 2037             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2038         except StopIteration:
   2039             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 110853, saw 10
```

Comment: It looks like some of your CSVs aren't really CSVs. `pandas` fails parsing them.

Comment: @Infinity I'd say more likely there's an error in that line on that file, such as a delimiter appearing inside of a field. That would explain how it got so far into the file before erroring (almost 111k lines)

Comment: @Infinity Oso is correct. There is a delimiter error in one of the files. Thanks to some of the helpful answers, I have added a try except block and it is returning the problematic file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your CSV's has an incorrect number of columns. It's on line 110853. You could add some test code to help troubleshoot it, like this:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Datapoints/*.txt'
dataframes = []
for filename in glob.iglob(path):
  try:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter='\t')
    data.head()
  except pd.errors.ParserError:
    print(f'Error in file: {filename}')
    raise
```

This should print out the filename that is causing the problem.

Note that I changed `glob.glob(path)` to `glob.iglob(path)`, which probably won't make much difference, unless you have an enormous number of files. `iglob` gives you an iterator, whereas `glob` gives a list, and then behind the scenes it ends up using the `list.__iter__` method in the same way. `iglob` will be slightly more efficient, and is a bit more pythonic.

Also, the `except` block ends with a `raise` statement, which is usually good practice when you do exception handling, since it prevents information about the error from being lost. It will also stop any additional files from being processed, which is a good thing in situations where the error is not recoverable and the code that caused the error should not be allowed to continue running.

Comment: it should output `Error in file: <filename>` to standard out. Are you using something like Jupyter notebook to run this code? I've seen stdout/stderr get sent to unexpected places in some setups using Jupyter and the like. You could try adding `import sys` at the top, and then change the print statement to `print(f'Error in file: {filename}', file=sys.stderr)`, that way it will for sure go to the same place as the stack trace. Also double check that it's not being printed before the error output (it should be the very first thing this program prints when it runs and hits an error).

Comment: I rewrote your code in IDLE and it worked! Thanks for that! I guess the error was in using JupyterLab.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that one of your csv is having some inconsistency, error or misleading structure and pandas is not able to figure out on its own how to read it. In the current message it is expecting 9 columns but finds 10 column in line 110853. This needs further investigation and for that you need to catch which file is causing this:

The following code will catch the `ParserError` exception and print the file name for you. Based on this you can start checking what's going on.

```
path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Datapoints/*.txt'
dataframes = []
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter='\t')
        dataframes.append(data)
    except pd.errors.ParserError as err:
        print(filename)
```